# Local GitLab runner freezes while Shared GitLab.com runner succeeds

Tags: python, gitlab, conda, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

EDIT: As Rekovni pointed out, using a GitLab runner with Docker on a Windows machine is a problem. **Installing the runner in a Linux-based virtual machine solved the problem.**

I am developing a Python program using a conda environment. It is hosted on GitLab.com and I am using GitLab-CI to generate the documentation.

I configured the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for it:

```yaml
image: continuumio/miniconda3:latest

before_script:
  # Update conda and create environment, which is then activated.
  - conda update -vvv -y -c conda-forge conda
  - conda env create -f helpers/NAME.yml
  - source activate NAME
  # Correct installation.
  - conda install -q -y gsl=2.2.1

pages:
  script:
    # Install make.
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -q -y build-essential
    # Install Spinx-related packages.
    - conda install -q -y sphinx sphinx_rtd_theme
    # Create documentation.
    - cd REPO/doc
    - sphinx-apidoc -o source/ ../REPO --force --separate
    - make html
    # Transfer documentation to public pages folder.
    - mv build/html/ ../../public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
#   only:
#     - master
```

Running this script with a shared GitLab runner that is supplied with GitLab.com works and the documentation is generated and placed in the public folder.

For future unit tests (which take much longer), I want to provide a local runner on a Win 10 machine in my network. For this, I installed the `gitlab-runner.exe` and Docker Desktop. I successfully registered the runner with the project on GitLab.com.

The runner is using the following `config.toml` configuration file:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
log_level = "info"

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "NAME"
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  token = "TOKEN"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

The problem is now that the local runner freezes during the execution of the above script without producing any error messages and I am at a loss on how to debug it. What I have is

1. The log of the script that is shown on the Job page on GitLab.com; and
2. The console output of the `gitlab-runner.exe` on the local machine.

Regarding 1., I see

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 11.10.0 (3001a600)
...
[32;1mChecking out COMMIT_HASH as BRANCH_NAME...[0;m
...
[0K[32;1m$ conda update -vvv -y -c conda-forge conda[0;m
DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(148): verbosity set to 3
...
...
...
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.update:rename(52): renaming /opt/conda/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/OSSL_STORE_LOADER_new.html => /opt/conda/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/OSSL_STORE_LOADER_new.html.c~
TRACE conda.core.path_actions:execute(1041): renaming share/doc/openssl/html/man3/OSSL_STORE_LOADER_set_close.html => share/doc/openssl/html/man3/OSSL_STORE_LOADER_set_close.html.c~
TRACE conda.gateways.disk.update:rename(52): renaming /opt/conda/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/OSSL_STORE_LOADER_set_close.html => /opt/conda/share/doc/openssl/html/man3/OSSL_STORE_LOADER_set_close.html.c~
TRACE conda.core.path_actions:execute(1041): renaming share/doc/openssl/html/man3/OSSL_STORE_LOADER_set_ctrl.html => share/doc/openssl/html/man3/OSSL_STORE_LOADER_set_ctrl.html.c~
```

where it abruptly stops without reaching the `- conda env create -f helpers/NAME.yml` line.

Regarding 2., I see

```
C:\GitLab-Runner>gitlab-runner.exe --debug run
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=14116 revision=3001a600 version=11.10.0Starting multi-runner from C:\GitLab-Runner\config.toml ...  builds=0
Checking runtime mode                               GOOS=windows uid=-1
Configuration loaded                                builds=0
...
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
Checking for jobs... nothing                        runner=TOKEN
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
Checking for jobs... received                       job=203033130 repo_url=REPO_URL.git runner=TOKEN
...
Attaching to container HASH ...  job=203033130 project=6249897 runner=TOKEN
Starting container HASH ...  job=203033130 project=6249897 runner=TOKEN
Waiting for attach to finish HASH ...  job=203033130 project=6249897 runner=TOKEN
Waiting for container HASH ...  job=203033130 project=6249897 runner=TOKEN
Appending trace to coordinator... ok                code=202 job=203033130 job-log=0-10348 job-status=running runner=TOKEN sent-log=1801-10347 status=202 Accepted
Appending trace to coordinator... ok                code=202 job=203033130 job-log=0-19445 job-status=running runner=TOKEN sent-log=10348-19444 status=202 Accepted
...
Appending trace to coordinator... ok                code=202 job=203033130 job-log=0-933150 job-status=running runner=TOKEN sent-log=241860-933149 status=202 Accepted
Submitting job to coordinator... ok                 code=200 job=203033130 job-status= runner=TOKEN 
Submitting job to coordinator... ok                 code=200 job=203033130 job-status= runner=TOKEN
```

where it seems that the switch from `Appending trace to coordinator` to `Submitting job to coordinator` happens around the time when it gets stuck.
After this, 1. is not updated with any further information and 2. is stuck in a `Submitting job to coordinator` loop.

Does anyone know:

1. What the reason for the failure with a local runner could be (when the same script works with a shared runner)?
2. What I could do to debug this problem?

Thanks and all the best,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab CI doesn't currently offer a solution for using its runner with Docker on a Windows environment, however there is an [epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/535) at the moment which is tracking progress for this.

In one of the [issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2609) of the epic, a contributer has managed to get a working version of a gitlab-runner which uses Docker for Windows, with which more details can be found [here](https://notes.alelec.net/blog/post/andrew@alelec.net/Windows-Docker-Gitlab-CI-Runner-2).

A more common (and potentially easier) way of using Docker in a Windows environment, would be to install the gitlab-runner as a Shell runner, and call the Docker commands manually to run your tests.

Conversely, if you just want to keep using the same CI script, you could install a Linux VM on your Windows 10 machine, and have that host the docker runner!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info. Just to be sure - what you mean is that currently, it is a problem to run a GitLab Runner together with Docker on a Windows machine. This has nothing to do with the Docker image itself - correct?.
Because in my case only the machine is Windows. The Docker image is Linux-based.

Comment: Well, that could be a separate issue entirely, would be worth reading something like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers

Comment: As you suggested, I hosted a VM with a Ubuntu client. In it, I installed the GitLab runner. This seems to work.